# How can I add line breaks in between code outputs in a MatLab live script?

Tags: matlab, formatting, format, printf, line-breaks

I have this code in a live script cell:

```
u = symunit; 

syms V_GS
V_t_value = 0.4*u.V;
K_n_W_L_value = 2*u.mA/u.V^2;

%get V_GS
i_d_equation_saturation = 0.5*K_n_W_L_value*(V_GS - V_t_value)^2; 
assume(V_GS >= V_t_value) %saturation region condition for V_GS is needed, otherwise the equation has two solutions

i_D_values = {50*u.uA, 200*u.uA};
for i = 1:2
    disp(replace(strcat('i_D = ', sym_with_units2str(i_D_values{i})), "mc", "u"))

    V_GS_value = solve(i_d_equation_saturation - i_D_values{i});

    %saturation region condition for V_DS
    V_DS_min = V_GS_value - V_t_value;
    V_GS_value = sym_with_units2str(V_GS_value)
    V_DS_min = sym_with_units2str(V_DS_min)
    disp(newline)
end
```

which outputs this:

[image]

I don't understand why it's not displaying a new line at the end of the loop like I told it to.  After a bunch of Googling, I've tried a bunch of variations of using `sprintf`, `fprintf`, and `disp`, as well as using `"\n"`, `"\r\n"`, and `char(10)` instead of `newline`, but nothing seems to work.  If I use the `fprintf` or `disp` function, it seems to just ignore it all together, regardless of whether use I `"\n"`, `newline`, or `char(10)` as the argument.  And if I use `sprintf`, it prints `ans = '  '`  instead of just inserting a line break line I want.

How can I get it to just display a line break?

And, just to be extra clear, so this doesn't get mistakenly closed as a duplicate, I'm *not* asking about how to insert a line break into a *string* -- I'm asking how to insert one between *code outputs* in a live script.  The various ways to add a line break to a string don't seem to work for adding one in between outputs.

Edit: Someone commented wanting to try running my exact code, I added the variable definitions at the top, and here's the function definition that I have defined in a separate file:

```
function svalue = sym_with_units2str(value)
    [value, unit] = separateUnits(value);
    svalue = strcat(sim2str(value), symunit2str(unit));
end
```

Comment: I can't run your exact code because you haven't defined all variables or functions, but reducing the code to `for i = 1:2, disp('abc'), disp(newline), end` I get the line breaks as expected. Have you redefined `newline` by any chance? Maybe try `clear newline`

Comment: @LuisMendo, Hmm.  When I run that line of sample code, I also get the line breaks,  I tried changing my code so I had the `disp(newline)` command on the same line as `V_DS_min`, with a comma separating them, but it didn't make a difference.  I also tried putting it on the same line as the display statement at the top of the loop, but that didn't make a difference either.  Any ideas?  I updated the post to include the variable and function definitions, if that helps.  Oh, and I double checked that there's no variable called newline in my workspace.

Comment: Did you try`clear newline`? Maybe you have redefined `newline` as `[]`... hard to tell, as the code you provide cannot be run

Answer (score 2):

I finally found something that works, so posting it in case anyone else has this same issue.

Replacing `disp(newline)` with `fprintf(' ')` or `disp(' ')` got it to show the line breaks.